# jQuery Post data to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I'm programming a registration page where the user first selects one of three options in the first page and only then can move onto the second page because it displays content that is dependent on the previous selection. So this is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var data= $(this).serialize();
        $.post("/Registration_1.php",data);
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>

<form id="frmtype1" name="frmtype1" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="1"/> option 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="2"/> option 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="3"/> option 3 <br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that after selecting an option and clicking submit it just stays on page 1. The alert displays the data, which is all correct but it just wont move to the next page. I'm brand new to jquery so i don't know if the $.post is syntactically correct. Can anyone see what the problem here is? Why won't it go to the next page? Thank you

Comment: Why not specify the page url in the `action` attribute of the form?

Answer (score 2):

Yo mate you need to define one more function which handles the success event of your post method. When your post is completed succesfully then you can change the URL like SomeKittens showed you.

```
$.post("/Registration_1.php",data,function(response){
     window.location = ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do specify the action in the form  like : **action="your url"**

for eg:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="http://stackoverflow.com/" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="1"/> option 1 <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="2"/> option 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="3"/> option 3 <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="s" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Modified script:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').on('click', function () {
            window.location('http://stackoverflow.com/');
        });
    });
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: i specifically didn't do that for a reason. I have the jquery stuff there to make sure that the user selects an option before submitting.

Comment: Well the .post you are using is to make ajax calls and i doubt you want to do that. So why dont you use your 'jquery stuff' that validates on submit call the window.location if it is valid? Simples

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$.post` is sending the data, but not redirecting the user.

[Here's a tutorial on how to redirect the user.](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Comment: I tried window.location="/Registration_1.php"; and "../Registration_1.php", neither seem to work.

Comment: Great question!  That's exactly the sort of thing you can Google to find out.